# Ejecutar compilado .exe de Python y Firebird/Interbase en diferentes versiones de Windows

Tags: python, windows, cx-freeze

Tengo un problema al ejecutar .exe compilados con cx_freeze a partir de un .py y ejecutarlos en distintas versiones de Windows, estas no tienen instalado Python.

¿El error puede deberse a que les hace falta la instalación de Python y las librerías que utilizo?

Él .exe está compilado en Windows, pero cuando lo ejecuto en otra máquina virtual con la misma versión me dice DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado y me hace referencia a kinterbasDB
ERROR

> ImportError: DLL load failed: This application has failed to start
> because the application configuration is incorrect.
>
> Reinstalling the application
>
> may fix this problem

Comment: Que yo sepa, los ejecutables .exe funcionan solamente en Windows.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza si me exprese mal, ya edite la publicación

Answer (score 2):

No vas a poder ejecutar `.exe` en diferentes sistemas operativos. La respuesta a tu pregunta sería que sólo vas a poder hacerlo en `Windows`. Si necesitas ejecutar tus scripts en algún otro sistema operativo deberás hacer el proceso de nuevo en ese sistema operativo (por lo que ya no será un `.exe`).

Sacado de la documentación de [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=linux):

> cx_Freeze works on Windows, Mac and Linux, but on each platform it
>   only makes an executable that runs on that platform. So if you want to
>   freeze your program for Windows, freeze it on Windows; if you want to
>   run it on Macs, freeze it on a Mac.

Que básicamente se traduce así:

> cx_Freeze funciona en Windows, Mac y Linux, pero en cada plataforma sólo
>   crea un ejecutable que funciona en dicha plataforma. Así que si quieres
>   crear un ejecutable para Windows, hazlo en Windows; si quieres hacer un 
>   ejecutable que corra en Mac, hazlo en Mac.

Comment: Si lo entiendo, me exprese mal... es en Windows pero en diferentes versiones. El .exe esta compilado en windows, pero cuando lo ejecuto en otra maquina virtual con la misma versión de windows me dice                         **DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el modulo especificado y me hace referencia a kinterbasdb**

Comment: Entiendo, ¿podrías editar tu pregunta agregando el error y los pasos para reproducirlo?

Answer (score 0):

**ERROR RESUELTO**..... La solución estaba en cargar el archivo `fbclient.dll` a System32 de Windows.
Este archivo es una Librería de enlace dinámico. 
Esta librería puede ser cargada y ejecutada en cualquier proceso en ejecución.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos